# Cannot invoke function with parameters in JBoss SEAM expression language

Tags: java, jboss, seam, el

I am trying to invoke the #{expressions.getClass()}, however I received exception. From the exception, it seems that characters like ( ) are not allowed. Please see following exception details:

```
    javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{
    org.jboss.seam.core.expressions.getClass()}
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValueBinding(Applicat
ionImpl.java:488)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplication11.createValueBinding(SeamApplicati
on11.java:143)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplication11.createValueBinding(SeamApplicati
on11.java:143)
    at com.successfactors.jsfcore.ui.config.SFApplication.createValueBinding
(SFApplication.java:355)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions$1.getFacesValueBinding(Expressions.ja
va:119)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions$1.getValue(Expressions.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Interpolator.interpolateExpressions(Interpolator.
java:88)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Interpolator.interpolate(Interpolator.java:67)
    ...
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{org.jboss.seam.core.expressions.getClass()}
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:125)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:194)
    at    org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValueBinding(ApplicationImpl.java:484)
    ... 87 more
    Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 43.
    Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Expression Language (or EL in short) one doesn't call methods, one resolves properties. Imagine you have a variable called `shop` in scope, in Java you would write

```
shop.getName()
```

whereas in EL you would write

```
#{shop.name}
```

The EL parser will invoke `getName()` for you.

Answer (score 0):

if your EL have parameter, you have to directly call method name.

El

```
#{MyBean.getName('Hello')}
#{MyBean.process(obj)}
```

Bean

```
public String getName(String value) {
    return value + " World!";
}

public void process(Object object) {
    //here your process
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but it does not work. I am able to retrieve property value for instance: myBean.name. I am able to execute function without argument for instance: myBean.execute. But I am not able to execute function with arguments for instance: myBean.execute(xxx).

Comment: @Mrwu Could you post page and bean?